# Stacktrace of exception visible locally, but not when deployed

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have those 2 straighforward controllers

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<SomeModel> Fail()
{
    throw new Exception("I always fail");
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<SomeModel>> Error()
{
    return BadRequest();
}
```

When I call them in local with Postman, I get what I expect:

a text/plain response for the exception, with the stacktrace

```
System.Exception: I always fail
   at ...
```

and a json-wrapped 400

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-c7e7c471ad9423ae766e657f4fee148f-edd007d34c34b05b-00"
}
```

But when I deploy the code in Service Fabric and call the remote server with Postman, for some reason, the exception doesn't get serialized and I get a blank 500 with no content. The 400 gets the same answer as in local (just used it in the example to prove that it's not some other issues like authentication problems)

Why?

Comment: You need to enable the developer error page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#developer-exception-page but it's a bit dangerous for production as it can expose interna info. Note that your `return BadRequest` is not being executed at all because there is no `catch`

Comment: seems you're right, after adding an exception handler, it seems to work better. Didn't know this peculiarity of C#, thank you

Comment: Not peculiar at all. If you throw an exception all the way out, the middleware needs to work out what to do with it. Whereas if you catch it yourself you can do your own handling. Or setup your own middleware error handling.